# (VBA Excel) Setting a style for result of .Find() is not working

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a function that queries a database for certain records and what I need to do is to be able to filter out the results. I figured the easiest way would be to use .Find method on a range and set the Style of cells, then filter based on the style. The problem that I'm experiencing is that I can't apply any transformation to cells for some reason. I can read the .Find result value though.
How do I change the style?

```
Public Function WoRecR(workOrders As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim command As Object
    Dim results As Object
    Dim searchResult As Range
    Dim field As Object
    Dim criteria As String

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set command = New ADODB.command
    Set results = New ADODB.Recordset
    criteria = ""

    For Each cell In workOrders
        If (Not IsEmpty(cell.Value)) Then
            criteria = "DOCINDEX1='" & cell.Value & "' OR " & criteria
        End If
    Next cell
    criteria = "(" & Left(criteria, Len(criteria) - 4) & ") "
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
                            "Persist Security Info=True;" & _
                            "Data Source=*********;" & _
                            "DATABASE=******;" & _
                            "UID=******;" & _
                            "PWD=******;"
        .Open
    End With
    On Error GoTo CloseCon
    command.ActiveConnection = cn
    command.CommandText = "SELECT DOCINDEX1 FROM PVDM_DOCS_1_4 WHERE " & criteria & " AND DOCINDEX9!='Phone' " & _
                          "AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, GETDATE(), DOCINDEX10) > -2;"
    command.CommandType = adCmdText
    command.Execute

    results.ActiveConnection = cn
    results.Open command

    While Not results.EOF
        Set searchResult = workOrders.Find(What:=results.Fields(0).Value)
        Debug.Print searchResult.Value
        searchResult.Style = "Good"
        results.MoveNext
    Wend
    cn.Close

CloseCon:
    If Err.Number Then Debug.Print Err.Description
End Function
```

The exact part of code that I'm referring to is this:

```
            While Not results.EOF
                Set searchResult = workOrders.Find(What:=results.Fields(0).Value)
                Debug.Print searchResult.Value
                searchResult.Style = "Good"
                results.MoveNext
            Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're getting a result from `.Find()`?  Try this, to be sure:

```
        While Not results.EOF
            Set searchResult = workOrders.Find(What:=results.Fields(0).Value)
            If Not searchResult is Nothing then
              Debug.Print searchResult.Value
              searchResult.Style = "Good"
            Else
              MsgBox ("nothing found") 'for debugging purposes only
            End If
            results.MoveNext
        Wend
```

Comment: Absolutely positive. The strange thing is that I'm able to set Style within regular Subs, but it seems that it does not work within custom functions. I tried to type in Range("B2:B10").Find(361656).Style = "Good" in my function and in a new macro. It only worked in a new macro. It looks like the Range is locked for editing.

Comment: You're saying that if you declare `Public Sub WoRecR(workOrders As Range)` it will work, but if you declare `Public Function WoRecR(workOrders As Range)` it doesn't? I'd change it to a `Sub` in that case, since you're not returning anything from your function. Also, I believe there is some sort of restriction on what can be changed in a `Function` vs a `Sub`.

Comment: I want to be able to invoke this as a spreadsheet function, that's why it's set up this way. Do you have a reference to those limitations? Or is there a work around?

Comment: A) I'm sorry, I don't have a list of restrictions, I've seen a couple of comments over the last several months that have made mention. Google might be your best buddy there. B) a `Function` is designed to return something, which your code does not. You would put `=WoRecR(A1)` in a cell, Excel is expecting you to return some sort of value for it to display in that cell, your code will disappoint. Since you want to do formatting, your best bet is to have a button or possibly an `OnChange` event trigger it to do the formatting.

Comment: I tried to google it, but wasn't able to find these. I guess I'll set it up as a Sub then. Thanks.